# Spring - Simply create Supplier<MyPrototypeBean>

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, prototype, factory, factory-pattern

I could not find a good and simple solution for my problem regarding different bean lifecycles.

I would like to inject a

```
@Resource
private Supplier<MessageHandler> messageHandlerFactory;
```

in a `@Service` bean to create a new MessageHandler instance (prototype, with its own dependencies) each time I call `messageHandlerFactory.get();`.

The solution I found named [Method Injection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-method-injection) seems overly complicated and cumbersome for such a common task.

What's the shortest and cleanest solution using a `@Configuration` class?

**== Update ==**

I just realized that Supplier should be [Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Provider.html) as defined in the [JSR-330](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define the Scope of your `MessageHandler` to be a `Prototype`:

```
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class MessageHandler {

}
```

And use an `ObjectFactory` to get the `MessageHandler` from the Singleton.

```
@Component
public class YourSingleton {

    @Autowired
    ObjectFactory<MessageHandler> mhFactory;

    public void doSomething() {
        final MessageHandler messageHandler = mhFactory.getObject();
        // messageHandler is a prototype
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's what I'm looking for. How could I now rewire mhFactory to create another MessageHandler?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Everytime you call `mhFactory.getObject()` you will get a **new** `MessageHandler` instance, because you have declared the `Scope` of it to be a `Prototype`. Do you want to wire the mhFactory again?

Comment: for testing I would like to rewire `mhFactory` to produce a `SomeChildMessageHandler`. How is that possible?

Comment: You can have a setter in `YourSingleton` and inject an anonymous class implementing `ObjectFactory<MessageHandler>` that returns the instance of `SomeChildMessageHandler.` Or you can mock it with `Mockito`, for example. If you need more details, you can create a new question, as it is difficult to explain this in a comment.